# Automorphism of the upper-half plane fixing 3 real value must be an identity

Tags: complex-analysis

For any automorphism of $\phi$ of the upper-half plane $\mathbb H$, if $\phi$ fixes $3$ values on the real axis, then $\phi=id$.

I am trying to use the formula for $Aut(\mathbb H)$ that I suppose $\phi(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ for some $ad-bc=1$. if $\phi$ fixes $z_0$, then $cz_0+(d-a)z-b=0$. I guess this should be useful. But I got stuck from here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You incorrectly rewrote the equation $\phi(z)=z$. Also, a hint: how many distinct roots a quadratic polynomial may have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developing @MoisheKohan's hint, we get that $cz^2+(d-a)z-b$ is the zero polynomial.   Thus  $b=c=0$ and $a=d $.

So $\phi (z)=z $.